# Wordpress-theme in html5 or xhtml?

Tags: wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

It's been a while with html5 floating around. Is it good to use it for a blog? It makes SEO better for sure, but does it harm the layout with older not-supporting-html5 browsers, like IE6?

Also, should i just copy parts from Twentyten, or code from scratch? Twentyten must be created by someone who knows how to create wordpress-theme.

Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good discussion on this topic here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/html-5-theme-for-wordpress-good-idea

And I think it is always a good choice to start from somewhere, whether it be twentyten, or one of the great theme frameworks out there (Thematic, WP Framework, etc.) so as to not reinvent the wheel with every custom theme.

:)

Answer (score 0):

TwentyTen is html5 valid: http://2010dev.wordpress.com/

But you may need this plugin to support the menus under IE6: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ie6-support-for-2010-theme/

Also, look into child themes for your own theme development: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

And check out 2010 Weaver: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/2010-weaver

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good HTML 5 themes available on the WordPress.org Theme Repository:

- [Just Css](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/justcss)
- [Toolbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox)
- [Baseline](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/room-34-baseline)

There is also:

[H5 from Digging Into WordPress](http://themeclubhouse.digwp.com/)

Most of these are very minimal and meant to be used as a framework or base starting theme.